# Submit POST request to Rails controller to modify model after creation, so the output of a javascript function becomes new model value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, httprequest, controllers

A user's address is a string, i.e. "401 Nina Place, Rockville MD 20852". After going through Google's Maps API, it becomes a Lat/Long pair.

I want to update two fields in my model (lat and long) after it runs through the javascript that calls Google's API using the first value in the model, the "home" string value (as above).

I have a users_controller.rb file, which contains the method edit_latlong. In my routes I have

```
  post 'ELL/' => 'users#edit_latlong'
```

Puma prints the following, which is the request I'm making in my home.html.erb:

```
Processing by UsersController#edit_latlong as JSON
  Parameters: {"params"=>{"id"=>"7", "lat"=>"39.0562619", "long"=>"-77.13000090000003"}}
```

Here is the code for the http request:

```
        $.ajax({ 
          type: 'POST', 
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/ELL/',
          data: { params: { id: '<%= current_user.id %>', lat: parseFloat(mrkr.position.A), long: parseFloat(mrkr.position.F) } },
          dataType: 'json'
        });
```

mrkr.position.A and mrkr.position.F both contain floats, as you can see above (they are actually strings, but I coerce them to floats... whatever).

Why does this request keep failing? I looked at the docs for controllers, and since I'm passing in id as a param, and then using it in my users_controller, I don't understand why it keeps failing.

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
    def edit_latlong
        @user = User.find(params["id"])
        @user.lat = params["lat"]
        @user.long = params["long"]
        @user.save()
    end
end
```

---

UPDATE:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'users#edit_latlong', 
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                  params: {
                    id: parseInt('<%= current_user.id %>'), 
                    lat: parseFloat(mrkr.position.A), 
                    long: parseFloat(mrkr.position.F)                        
                  }
                },
                dataType: 'json'
              });


class UsersController < ActionController::Base
    def edit_latlong
        @user = User.find(params["id"])
        @user.update(lat: params["lat"], long: params["long"] )
        @user.save!
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
  post 'users#edit_latlong' => 'users#edit_latlong'
```

Guard output:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-05-19 23:39:52 -0400
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"params"=>{"id"=>"7", "lat"=>"39.0562619", "long"=>"-77.13000090000003"}}
Geokit is using the domain: localhost
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.7ms)
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 7  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 158ms (Views: 150.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Thing's I'm noticing: 
1) Even if I output using `logger.debug blah,blah` it doesn't output to console.
2) Someone the JSON of the parameters is treating everything as a String even though I'm coercing stuff to floats and ints
3) The ajax request has a different structure than what I'm reading in the controller. It is data:{params:{id:X, lat:Y, long:Z}} even though I just treat it as params["id"], params["lat"], params["long"] (just wanted to point out some things I'm noticing

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: The user model is not getting updated

Comment: try changing `@user.save()` to `@user.save!` and then check if there's any errors being raised, it will help you know the problem, then update the question to get more help

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
    def edit_latlong
        @user = User.find(params["id"])
        @user.update(lat: params["lat"], long: params["long"] )
    end
end
```

remember check if update success acording to your workflow

EDIT:

maybe you have wrong `data` syntax in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/ELL/',
    data: { id: '<%= current_user.id %>', lat: parseFloat(mrkr.position.A), long: parseFloat(mrkr.position.F) },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: I am using Devise, so I don't think there is a corresponding update function like what you're telling me. I believe I should be able to call the fields directly, since I am "permitting" them through